# Mail Laravel 5.4 (Mailables) No funciona y no da error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

**Controller:**

```
$sent = Mail::to('correo@correo.es')->send(new Welcome($name, $email, $phone, $msg));
```

**.env:**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.dominio.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=no_reply@correo.es
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

**Vista:**

```
<h3>Contacto Web</h3>
<br>
<br>
<b>Nombre:</b> {{$name}}
<br>
<b>Email:</b> {{$email}}
<br>
<b>Teléfono:</b> {{$phone}}
<br>
<b>Mensaje:</b> {{$msg}}
```

**Mailable:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable; use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable; use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels; use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class Welcome extends Mailable {

    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $phone;
    public $msg;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @param $name
     * @param $email
     * @param $phone
     * @param $msg
     */
    public function __construct($name, $email, $phone, $msg)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->phone = $phone;
        $this->msg = $msg;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {

        $address = 'correo@correo.es';
        $dest_name = 'Web';
        $subject = 'Contacto Web';

        return $this->view('emails.welcome')
            ->to($address, $dest_name)
            ->from($this->email, $this->name)
            ->subject($subject);

    } }
```

En teoria este código me funcionaba hasta ahora y de repente ha dejado de mandar correos, no muestra ningún error. He probado de cambiar el **send** por **queue** y no cambia nada. Ya no se que más probar, he creado un mailable nuevo y lo mismo.

**Versión:** Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de hacer bastantes pruebas, llegué a la conclusión que de sólo me faltaba una cosa para comprobar.... Aver si la IP del servidor estaba bloqueada por SPAM o algo.... y efectivamente me habían bloqueado y el motivo era por MAIL SPOOFING, por lo tanto la clase Mailable quedaría así.

Puesto que lo que yo hacía era coger el correo que me escribían en el formulario y meterlo en el from como si esa cuenta hubiera mandado el correo directamente.

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable; use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable; use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels; use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class Welcome extends Mailable {

    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $phone;
    public $msg;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @param $name
     * @param $email
     * @param $phone
     * @param $msg
     */
    public function __construct($name, $email, $phone, $msg)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->phone = $phone;
        $this->msg = $msg;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {

        $address = 'correo@correo.es';
        $dest_name = 'Web';
        $subject = 'Contacto Web';

        return $this->view('emails.welcome')
            ->to($address, $dest_name)
            ->from('no_reply@correo.es', $this->name)
            ->subject($subject);

    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Que servidor estas usando?
Estos datos espero que sean solo muestra, sino este es el problema

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.dominio.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=no_reply@correo.es
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

También hay compañías de correos como sendgrid que te ponen limite mensual y si lo sobrepasas te dejan los correos en "espera" para ser mandados en cuanto acabe el mes y empiece el siguiente

Comment: Son solo de muestra, estoy en local ahora mismo pero el correo es de DonDominio.

Comment: o se que política tendrá esa empresa, pero prueba a ver si envía desde el webmail y también intenta configurar un código php simple con esos parámetros a ver si no es cosa de Laravel (que es lo mas probable).

Comment: Por lo visto si es cosa de Laravel. Usando mail de PHP funciona perfectamente.

$sent = mail('correo@correo.es', 'PRUEBA', $msg);

Comment: Cambia el driver a mail y usara la función de tu servidor, sino, mira en config/mail.php

Comment: Falsa alarma, no me funciona la función de PHP. Era otro correo que me ha entrado.... En otra web que funcionaba ahora tampoco funciona, no hemos actualizado composer ni hemos cambiado nada.... en local y tampoco funciona. Seguiré investigando....